# Native base list item click event not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I have started learning react native 2 days back only. I am using list item component from [Native Base](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref) UI framework.

According to their docs and examples to catch a click event on `ListItem` you need to add `onPress` and `button` option to the ListItem. But in my case its not working.

I have another element with also tracks click event, it works fine, but list element isn't catching click event.

Strange this is that if I trigger a alert, it works

```
<List button onPress={() => { Alert.alert('Item got clicked!') } }>
```

Below id my complete code

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { 
    Content, 
    List, 
    ListItem, 
    Body, 
    Thumbnail, 
    Text, 
    Badge, 
    View 
  } from 'native-base';
  import { ActivityIndicator, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';

  export default class Questions extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(){
      Alert.alert("I am clicked");
      // Call method from parent
      this.props.onPress();
    }

    render() {
        var items = this.props.items;

        return (
          <Content>
            <List button onPress={() => { this.handleClick } }>
                {Object.keys(items).map(function(eachQuestion) {
                  return (
                    <ListItem avatar key={items[eachQuestion].id} button onPress={() => { this.handleClick } } >
                      <Body>
                        <Text>{items[eachQuestion].question}</Text>
                      </Body>
                    </ListItem>
                  )
                })}  
            </List>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleClick}> 
                <View><Text>Click me</Text></View> 
            </TouchableOpacity>          
          </Content>  
        ); 

   }
  }
```

**Edit 1**

```
    render() {
        var questions = {
          "1" : "James", 
          "2" : "Smith", 
          "3" : "Doe", 
          "4" : "Smith"
        };

        return (
          <Container>
            <Content>
              <List>
                {Object.keys(questions).map(function(key) {
                  return (<ListItem button={true} onPress={this.handleClick}>
                            <Text>{questions[key]}</Text>
                          </ListItem>
                  )        
                })}
              </List>
            </Content>
          </Container>        
        ); 
    }
```

** Final Solution **

```
handleClick(){
  Alert.alert("I got clicked");
}

render() {
  var questions = this.props.questions;

  return (
    <Content>
      <List>
          {Object.keys(questions).map((eachQuestion) => { 
            return (
                <ListItem key={questions[eachQuestion].id} button={true} onPress={this.handleClick} >
                  <Body>
                    <Text>{questions[eachQuestion].question}</Text>
                  </Body>
                </ListItem>
            )
          })}  
      </List>
    </Content>  
  );
```

}

Comment: Not sure is it a typo but you are missing out the closing tag for `Body`.

Comment: In actual code closing body tag is there. While posting code here i cleaned some come, in between i might have deleted that code. But thats not the problem for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two errors:

1. You should brush up on your ES6 [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You aren't calling your `handleClick` function which is why nothing is happening vs your `Alert` example where it does work (since you are actually doing something).
2. You don't define the value for the `button` prop. The docs say that there is no default value, so it's good practice to define it as `true` or `false`.

So to fix your code, you should define your props for `ListItem` like so:

```
button={true}
onPress={() => { this.handleClick() }}
```

OR to make it shorter:

```
button={true}
onPress={this.handleClick}
```

I'm also not sure why you are defining `button` and `onPress` props on your `List` component since it's the `ListItem`s that you are trying to click, not the entire `List` itself. But since that isn't part of the question, I won't address that.

Full example of working code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, List, ListItem, Text } from 'native-base';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    Alert.alert("I am clicked");
    // Call method from parent
    //this.props.onPress();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <List>
            <ListItem button={true} onPress={this.handleClick}>
              <Text>Simon Mignolet</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button={true} onPress={() => { this.handleClick() }}>
              <Text>Nathaniel Clyne</Text>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button={true} onPress={this.handleClick}>
              <Text>Dejan Lovren</Text>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution didnt work, I just found this example from their docs, it looks same like mine code. http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.9/components#listOnClick

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me I tested the code before posting. It should work. What does your edited code look like. I'll even post the example code I used from the docs showing it working.

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me Do note that those docs are from v0.5.9. The current version of NativeBase is v2.1.5. So unless you are using a very out of date version of NativeBase, do not always trust the docs from older versions. It's possible that the `button` prop from that version had a default value (and it's possible that it's still there even now). However, if the docs explicitly tell you that there is no default value like the current docs do, then you *should* be defining it.

Comment: Strange, Your code works great, but when i loop <listItems> using Object.keys, it stops working again. I have added my updated code to question as "Edit 1"

Comment: @www.amitpatil.me Based on "Edit 1", try changing your callback in `map` to use arrow function expression. `Object.keys(questions).map((key) => { ... })`

Comment: @max23_ : It worked Thanks a lot! i was struggling with it for hours.